# Failed to fetch debian packages while building dockerfile from php:7.3.29-fpm-stretch

Tags: debian, apt, docker, php

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.29-fpm-stretch

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i s/deb.archive.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Build Logs:

```
=> CACHED [10/31] RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [11/31] RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/i  1.1s
------                                                                                                                                        
 > [11/31] RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ --with-xpm-dir=/usr/include/ --enable-gd-jis-conv:                                                                                                  
#14 0.246 Configuring for:                                                                                                                    
#14 0.246 PHP Api Version:         20180731                                                                                                   
#14 0.246 Zend Module Api No:      20180731                                                                                                   
#14 0.246 Zend Extension Api No:   320180731
#14 0.684 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#14 0.685 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#14 0.687 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#14 0.708 checking for cc... cc
#14 0.727 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#14 0.762 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#14 0.762 checking for suffix of executables... 
#14 0.786 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#14 0.815 checking for suffix of object files... o
#14 0.831 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#14 0.846 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#14 0.860 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#14 0.883 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#14 0.910 checking for icc... no
#14 0.914 checking for suncc... no
#14 0.919 checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
#14 0.946 checking for system library directory... lib
#14 0.946 checking if compiler supports -R... no
#14 0.954 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#14 0.981 checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
#14 0.987 checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
#14 0.987 checking target system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
#14 1.009 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
#14 1.009 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
#14 1.009 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731
#14 1.010 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#14 1.010 checking if debug is enabled... no
#14 1.024 checking if zts is enabled... no
#14 1.037 checking for re2c... re2c
#14 1.038 checking for re2c version... 0.16 (ok)
#14 1.041 checking for gawk... no
#14 1.042 checking for nawk... nawk
#14 1.043 checking if nawk is broken... no
#14 1.043 checking for GD support... yes, shared
#14 1.044 checking for the location of libwebp... no
#14 1.044 checking for the location of libjpeg... /usr/include/
#14 1.044 checking for the location of libpng... /usr/include/
#14 1.044 checking for the location of libz... no
#14 1.045 checking for the location of libXpm... /usr/include/
#14 1.045 checking for FreeType 2... /usr/include/
#14 1.045 checking whether to enable JIS-mapped Japanese font support in GD... yes
#14 1.049 If configure fails try --with-webp-dir=<DIR>
#14 1.049 configure: error: jpeglib.h not found.
```

This Dockerfile used to build fine and has only recently started throwing this error